# Turning pdf tables into html tables

Tags: html, pdf

I need to convert pdf or google doc tables into html tables. Where can I achieve that. I have tired a few place, but they give me span and css and i don't want to be heavy i need html table

Comment: What have you tried ? Which programming language are you using ? Show us your codes.

Comment: What you perceive as a PDF table usually merely is a collection of text somehow absolutely positioned and possibly some lines inbetween or some filled rectangles underneath. Thus, *not* getting html tables as a result of the transformation is quite natural.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23495372/extract-table-data-from-pdf

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this question. If you are looking to turn a PDF table into a HTML table. Drag the file into Google Drive and then click on the file and click open up with Google Doc then simple drag select the table and paste it wherever it should automatically be HTML table format. Hope this helps.